# How to avoid the "requested module does not provide an export named" error in typescript + Vue 3?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

I have this interface:

Product.ts

```
import { Category } from "@/Models/Category";

export interface Product {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    slug: string;
    description: string;
    price: number;
    categories: Category[];
    quantity: number;
}
```

and Category.ts

```
import { Product } from "@/Models/Product"

export interface Category {    
    id: number
    name: string
    slug: string
    // relations
    products: Product[]   
}
```

And then I am getting this error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module
> '/src/Models/Product.ts?t=1654212769656' does not provide an export
> named 'Product' (at Category.ts:1:1)

I try to solve using export default, and remove the brackets in the file that is importing, but the error remains, what can I do?

This is my tsconfig.json

```
{
  "extends": "@vue/tsconfig/tsconfig.web.json",
  "include": ["env.d.ts", "src/**/*", "src/**/*.vue"],
  "compilerOptions": {    
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./src/*"]
    }        
  },

  "references": [
    {
      "path": "./tsconfig.vite-config.json"
    }
  ]
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: It's probably caused by the circular dependency.

Comment: Is there no other content in these files? Try `import type`, it could be handled differently.

Comment: Thanks @tony19 and @estus-flask for responding, I just did what @estus-flask mentioned and now it is working, thanks, but I was wondering why, because I have seen other examples and it is not required to add `import type` . thanks again

Answer (score 0):

The correct way of by using 'import type { Category } from "@/Models/Category