# The requested module '/_nuxt/models/component/blog/BlogPage.interface.ts' does not provide an export named 'default' - Nuxt 3 TypeScript Error

Tags: typescript, types, import, model, nuxtjs3

I use Typescript in nuxt 3 project and I'm getting this error when I import typescript models from compoents.

```
The requested module '/_nuxt/models/component/blog/BlogPage.interface.ts' does not provide an export named 'default'
```

This is my component. **ComponentRenderer.vue**

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import BlogPage from "~~/models/component/blog/BlogPage.interface";
import HomePage from "~~/models/component/home/HomePage.interface";
import ProductPage from "~~/models/component/product/ProductPage.interface";

const props = defineProps<{
  page: HomePage | ProductPage | BlogPage;
}>();
console.log(typeof props.page);
</script>
```

and this is the imported model. **BlogPage.interface.ts**

```
interface BlogPage {
  data: any;
}

export default BlogPage;
```

finally this is my **nuxt.config.ts**

```
// https://nuxt.com/docs/api/configuration/nuxt-config
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  alias: {
    'models': './models/*',
  },
  typescript: {
    strict: true,
  },
  css: ["~/assets/css/main.css"],
  modules: ["@pinia/nuxt", "@nuxtjs/apollo"],
  postcss: {
    plugins: {
      tailwindcss: {},
      autoprefixer: {},
    },
  },
  pinia: {
    autoImports: ["defineStore"],
  },
  apollo: {
    autoImports: true,
    authType: "Bearer",
    authHeader: "Authorization",
    tokenStorage: "cookie",
    clients: {
      default: {
        httpEndpoint: "http://localhost:1337/graphql",
      },
    },
  },
});
```

As I check every where I don't see any issue in my implementation but this error keep appearing. I want to check how I can fix this issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a solution in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72483310/how-to-avoid-the-requested-module-does-not-provide-an-export-named-error-in-ty). Check [Estus Flask](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3731501/estus-flask) answer. As he mentioned in that comment I have changed my import statements as below.

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import type BlogPage from "~~/models/component/blog/BlogPage.interface";
import type HomePage from "~~/models/component/home/HomePage.interface";
import type ProductPage from "~~/models/component/product/ProductPage.interface";

const props = defineProps<{
  page: HomePage | ProductPage | BlogPage;
}>();
console.log(typeof props.page);
</script>
```

adding `type` after `import` will fix this error. But even without `type` my implementation was not wrong according to the theory. But some how it didn't work in my Nuxt 3 typescript implementation. So I used,

```
import type
```

Comment: Why is this happening? In the 3.0.0 project, everything worked for me without `type`, but on `3.3.2` it is already required